# Permanently set Font size and font selection in vim (compiled from source)

Tags: vimrc, font

I have searched both Stack Overflow and the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange sites and the few questions regarding font size in vim are regarding gvim and the guifont. However, I am using vim from command line. Some of the posts are regarding setting font size on the fly, which also does not apply to my situation.

I have a two part question.

**First part:** How do I permanently enlarge the display font size? (Poor vision necessitates this.)

**Second part:** How do I set the font to be displayed?

I am separating these points, because I may choose to just enlarge the default font (whatever that is.)

I have compiled vim from source and am using version 7.4.899. When configuring the source code, I used

```
--with-features=huge --enable-multibyte
```

I am hoping for a simple solution in the .vimrc file, but would rebuild from source if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change the font face and the font size in GVim/MacVim.

If you use Vim in a terminal emulator you will have to do that in your terminal emulator.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Now if only I could set the font size in the terminal to be language specific. :)

Comment: Actually, after further research this is theoretically possible by changing the default fallback font as asked [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215245/how-to-change-default-fallback-font-for-non-latin-languages)